# Targeting specific div/slider within a page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using the DIVI theme and have two sliders at the top and bottom of the page.

This is the link to the website:

http://platinum.calvinchhor.com/

I've adjusting the height of the slider using:

```
.et-pb-active-slide {
height: 1200px;
}
```

It works great for the first slider but I want to decrease the size of the second slider at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change into class #left-area**

> {
>       float: left;
>       margin-right: 0;
>       width: 100%; }

Answer (score 0):

This is not about showing sidebar container. Your left area container `#left-area` has its width set to `720px` so it's causing a problem. You can just try to add this line to your **custom theme css** file:

```
#left-area {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that Ravi has already answered. He is right as well of course, but setting float and margin may not be necessary, since it is already set there as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks! Your're both awesome!